# How browser decides what to use: http or https (tinymce load of @font-face error)

Tags: css, browser, tinymce, font-face

I have problem with tinymce 4.1.10. Icons are not shown in it, then i put it in page, that is loaded through https. Problem is that font files are loaded through http and browser writes in console:

> Mixed Content: ... was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure
>   font '...tinymce.woff'. This request has been blocked; the content
>   must be served over HTTPS.

Css file with reference to tinymce.woff tinymce/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css is loaded through https. It contains relative link to the font file.

I tried to test how it is loaded in tinymce site: https://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php And it works here! Font file tinymce.woff is loaded though https. Files skin.min.css are identical in tinymce.com and in my server and both loaded by https, but why font file tinymce.woff is loaded through http on my site (and through https in tinymce site)?
What makes browser (i tested in FF and Chrome) to decide to use http or https?

PS. I read similar questions here and played with http headers, but it didn't help.

Comment: Not sure where the confusion lies. Browsers decide between using http or https by the URI. So if some content gets loaded through http, you must have a "http" in your source somewhere! What is the site where you have this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found solution. Problem was in .htaccess file in my server, that redirected some https calls to http. Thank you all, who read this and tried to answer :)

Comment: Oh, so I was wrong in my comment. The problem could also be somewhere else than in your source. Thanks for enlightening me!